# Hibernate with jpa 2.1 SerialContext cannot be cast to DataSource

Tags: hibernate, java-ee-7, glassfish-4

I am trying to get hibernate to work with JPA, glassfish and Java EE7. But I don't seem to have any luck so far. I constantly get this error that I cannot solve when I try to create an `EntityManagerFactory`.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext cannot be cast to javax.sql.DataSource
```

The log:

```
Severe:   Exception while loading the app
Severe:   Undeployment failed for context /kwitter
Severe:   Exception while loading the app : javax.ejb.CreateException: Initialization failed for Singleton InitCoffee
javax.ejb.CreateException: Initialization failed for Singleton InitCoffee
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.createSingletonEJB(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:476)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.access$000(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:74)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer$SingletonContextFactory.create(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:647)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.instantiateSingletonInstance(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.SingletonLifeCycleManager.initializeSingleton(SingletonLifeCycleManager.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.SingletonLifeCycleManager.initializeSingleton(SingletonLifeCycleManager.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.SingletonLifeCycleManager.doStartup(SingletonLifeCycleManager.java:158)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.start(EjbApplication.java:169)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:353)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:501)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:220)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:487)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:466)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:169)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:526)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to build entity manager factory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:81)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at david.twitter.InitCoffee.init(InitCoffee.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.BeanCallbackInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:1047)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackChainImpl.invokeNext(CallbackChainImpl.java:72)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInvocationContext.proceed(CallbackInvocationContext.java:205)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:73)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:998)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackChainImpl.invokeNext(CallbackChainImpl.java:72)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInvocationContext.proceed(CallbackInvocationContext.java:205)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.init(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:998)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackChainImpl.invokeNext(CallbackChainImpl.java:72)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:417)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:380)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:1962)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.createSingletonEJB(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:468)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext cannot be cast to javax.sql.DataSource
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1885)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1843)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:843)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:399)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:842)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:73)
    ... 80 more
```

The class that should create the entitymanager:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class InitCoffee {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

         EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("kwetter");
       //EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

        System.out.println("did the init");
    }

}
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="kwetter" transaction-type="JTA">
   <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:app/kwitter</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.SunOneJtaPlatform"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/kwetter"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value=""/>
      <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
      <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And the Pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.8.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.27</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Is there a reason that you are using a Singleton to initialize the persistence context instead of the [@PersistenceContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/PersistenceContext.html) annotation?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is in your `persistence.xml` as proved by the error:

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to build entity manager
>   factory

Looking at your dependencies, you are mixing up eclipselink and hibernate. Both are JPA implementations. If I am correct, Glassfish has a default implementation for eclipselink, so you should probably stick with that one. Look at [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24930/jpa.htm#GSDVG00138) for a correct implementation.

If you really want to use hibernate, use a dependency on [`org.hibernate.javax.persistence`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence) instead of the `org.eclipselink.persistence`.

Further, the [`@PersistenceContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/PersistenceContext.html) annotation can be used instead of the Singleton class you are using.